# tensorflow No gradients provided for any variable when using custom training function

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I used the code from [tensorflow example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit?_gl=1*1wj8amv*_ga*MzE2ODY1MTkwLjE2NTg0OTY2MTg.*_ga_W0YLR4190T*MTY3NDY1ODc3MS4xLjAuMTY3NDY1ODc4MC4wLjAuMA..) and modified the custom training function to use RL epsilon greedy policy for action selection. However, gradient calculations are no longer working. Can someone point out what is missing in my logic for gradient descent?

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass

>             # Compute our own loss
>             metric = tf.math.argmin(y_pred, axis=1)

            loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y, metric)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Compute our own metrics
        loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        mae_metric.update_state(y, y_pred)
        return {"loss": loss_tracker.result(), "mae": mae_metric.result()}
```

Here is the error message from TensofFlow:

```
     grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    /home/share/virtualenvs/TxBsk36Y/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/utils.py:79 filter_empty_gradients
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0'].
```

Comment: argmin is not a differentiable operation.

Comment: @learner [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.04627.pdf) suggest argmin differentiation. However, I am looking for more practical solution.